# mktime function in php not working properly

Tags: php

I am using code:

```
$old_month = strtolower(date("m", mktime(date('H'), date('i'), date('s'), (date('m')-12),date('d'), date('Y'))));
$old_year = strtolower(date("Y", mktime(date('H'), date('i'), date('s'), (date('m')-12), date('d'), date('Y'))));


if ( $profile_stats['month'] < $old_month && $profile_stats['year'] == $old_year
|| $profile_stats['month'] == date('m') && $profile_stats['year'] == date('Y') )
```

The If loop should take value of the last month..i.e. Its october now..so If should search for sept ie. 9

How can I achieve that.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php script getting month error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960824/php-script-getting-month-error)

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$old_month = strtolower(date("m", strtotime("lastmonth"));


if ( $profile_stats['month'] < $old_month && $profile_stats['year'] == $old_year
|| $profile_stats['month'] == date('m') && $profile_stats['year'] == date('Y') )
```

should be

```
if ( strtotime($profile_stats['month']) < strtotime($old_month) && strtotime($profile_stats['year']) == strtotime($old_year)
|| $profile_stats['month'] == date('m') && $profile_stats['year'] == date('Y') )
```

Comment: @user1757184 isn't it giving the proper answer?

Comment: Its giving blank page..can you tell me your skype or gmail ID..please I need this to correct as I messed it up.

Comment: I am just nearby you...at Sriganganagar. If you give me, It'll help me a lot.

Comment: @user1757184 due to SO security reason i cannot provide that..You can share a link ...on `codepad` or `phpfiddle`

Comment: Okay...just see the code http://codepad.org/oujYGlOv It is used to print a stats i.e. views, visits etc. to the page upto last month..but Its showing me only upto May. I am not expert..If you give it a glance that would be great. I am ready to provide you every info.

Comment: See the image to know...what this file prints tinypic.com/r/ea1kjm/6

Comment: @user1757184 i can't check anything in such a long file.

Comment: Just see the pictue  tinypic.com/r/ea1kjm/6 ..It'll give you hint. From line no 360 upto 426

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be subtracting 12 from the number of months. That would make it last year.

Try using English - `strtotime` is surprisingly good at handling that:

```
$last_month = strtotime("-1 month");
list($old_month,$old_year) = explode("-",date("m-Y",$last_month));
```

Comment: don't suggest strtotime. use DateTime and a 1month interval.

Comment: Please see this question now.